# Error dumping data from a local db for a meteor server

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I want to upload data from a local db to a meteor server. After running `mongodump -h 127.0.0.1:3002 -d meteor -o meteor` the terminal returns the following error:

```
2015-05-28T20:47:14.125-0700 warning: Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:3002, reason: errno:61 Connection refused couldn't connect to [127.0.0.1:3002] couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:3002 (127.0.0.1), connection attempt failed
```

Is there any way to fix the problem? No similar post provides a workaround.

Comment: were you able to connect to that mongo server using mongo command,is the mongod instance running ,Type some query and see if it is working fine

Comment: Could you be more specific?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The port is no longer port 3002 (port of your meteor app 3000 + 2). Now it is the port + 1. So if you run Meteor on port 3000, you need to connect to port 3001:

```
mongodump -h 127.0.0.1:3001 -d meteor -o meteor
```

Comment: I alternated between port 3000, 3001, 3002. These returned the same errors.

Comment: @Eric What port does your meteor app run on? And on what server? This is fairly trivial it works on nearly every platform i've tried, there's not much to it. Make sure meteor is running when you try it

Comment: There it is! The app must be running. Thanks for the tip, Akshat!